# Why did my percentage of ranking change so much in my Stack Overflow profile?

Tags: support, reputation, reputation-leagues

As you can see in the image below I'm currently in the "top 20% overall" group. A few days ago (may be up to December) it was showing something like 0.053% when my reputation was less than 1500, and it was changing while my reputation was increasing, but I am sure the numbers were like I said, 0.053%, and for the past few days (may be since the start of this year) it has changed to 20%.

So I am not getting clear why the percentage has changed so much though my reputation didn't change such high. What are the reasons behind this?

[image: Current rep with top 20 overall]

Comment: 0.053% for "overall" does not sound right if you rep is 1908 - are you sure that is correct?... 20% looks reasonable - if clicking on that link does not explain what it is - clarify your post on what exactly you interested in.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - Updated the question, please check

Comment: It is a link; have you clicked it to see where it goes?

Comment: There is a good chance it was showing "top X per month" as for November https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/month/stackoverflow/2017-11-01 you had pretty high rating. I never paid much attention to that field - so maybe it varies per week.

Comment: @TylerH - Yes i have seen

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov - You might be right, it is sure that when it was like 0.053%, the word 'overall' was not there, but i can't remember what was exactly!

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: oh the irony that I was trying to answer your meta question as you closed it. ;)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I was kidding :o

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels :) I'll sit on [it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361891/how-to-better-guess-that-question-will-be-deleted-by-op) and probably undelete at some point when I figure out how to convert it into something less of a rant. How many times I said - downvote and move on... and still not follow that advice myself enough :).  Managed to collect whole 3 views in couple seconds so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe it typically shows whatever reputation league you are highest in - if you are higher relative rank in 'overall', it will show that; if you are higher relative rank in 'this week' or 'this quarter', etc., it will show that.

For example, mine says "top 3% overall". For the current "week" league, I am much lower percentage rank, and the same goes for the current "month" and "quarter" league. Therefore, mine shows the overall ranking.

You can view user reputation leagues here: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

Means that you are in the **top 20% of raked users (by reputation)**. "Overall" means that it is not a yearly, monthly, etc., ranking, but rather the **total reputation count**.